# indexing MySQL in Apache Solr

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, indexing

I am trying to build a search engine for my application. I have a mysql database having nearly 150 tables. Each table has a unique field called DB_ID And various other columns. Now when I am indexing the data using Apache solr is it sufficient to index only the DB_ID column? Also I am very new to Solr and from the tutorials I couldnt find how to index multiple tables in Solr. In my case I have around 150 tables. SO how do I go about the problem?

Comment: Also I must mention that the various fields in diff tables are different. There are no common fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB_ID is probably not a useful item to index.  If you want to be able to search records of all the tables in your database generically, you would probably need to *store* the DB_IDs and table names of each record, and *index* any other fields that you wish to be able to search on.  You can index all these fields using the same field name (say "`content`").  This would allow searching across every record of each table with a simple search on the `content` field.  I would guess it would be useful to also index the table name as well as storing it, so that you could optionally search only one table, or a subset of tables records.

Once a DB record had been found in your index, you could then fetch the table name and DB_ID and retrieve the record from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I am still not sure how to import nearly 150 tables to Solr where the tables dont have any common field. Also I read somewhere that generally we index fields having unique values. Is it always necessary to index the field on which we are running the search?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by indexing fields having unique values, really.  It's typical to store only a unique identifier in order to pull complete records from another data source (commonly, a database).  But yes, you must index a field to search on it.  You don't need to *store* the value to search on it, but you must *index* it.

Comment: Any help regarding the joining multiple tables in solr?

Comment: Apart from the possibility of just storing them in a generic content field, not really.  I would probably just iterate through the rows of each record adding them to the content field, if I understand what your looking for, but it does depend on your data and how you will need to handle it or search for it.